# Performance of JSON Parse/Stringify

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to store a maximum of around 10 thousand integers in sessionStorage. I will need to JSON parse and stringify to update this array of integers.

Is this a terrible idea? Or is the performance hit not too bad?

Comment: With performance the advice is always to try it and see.  10k items shouldn't be a performance slowdown, though.

Comment: Just done a quick test,.. Storing 10,000 integer with stringify and sessionStorage, about 11ms,  retrieving from sessionStorage, and parse.  about 8ms..

Comment: depends on where/when he does it then. 11ms will almost certainly drop a frame, and I'm presuming you didn't test on a medium to low end device? might be kinda bad on a older phone.

Comment: OP, any chance you can use web workers for some of the work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use SessionStorage for that purpose because it is blocking main thread that can leads to hanging your application.

Check [IndexedDb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) instead

It designed to be async and more-less fast. And also it has pretty nice support:

[image]
https://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb

Hope this helps

Comment: @Keith Agree. But if he already has to store 10 000 items, that there is a non null possibility that this number will grow. And grow :) So, at least it worth checking, I think.

Comment: @Vitalii 10k is the theoretical max. 500 is average for my situation.

Comment: @TimMorris Sure, it's up to you to design the solution. I just want to mention that changing approach from sync to async can take some time. And as other mentioned, Core I7 and Intel Atom will have very different performance ;)

Comment: @Vitalii I'm looking into IndexedDB anyhow. Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 2):

As @IrkenInvader said test and measure on your reference browser(eg. on low end mobile device parsing can be much slower).

A quick test:

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
var numbers = Array.apply(null, {length: 10000}).map(Function.call, (x) => getRandomInt(100));
var start = window.performance.now();
window.sessionStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(numbers));
var end = window.performance.now();
console.log("timing", end-start);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will probably depend on the browser implementation of the JSON module and much more other factors. From my tests in Chrome `JSON.stringify` will be much faster than `Array.join` - but when parsing it, `String.split` seems to be faster. As long as you can rely on the array content to be exclusively numbers, you can just `String.slice(-1, 1)` the JSON string and then split it.

```js
// Generate 10k/1m numbers in a range of 100 to 300 mio
let intsTK = [], intsM = [], min = 100000000, max = 300000000
for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  let r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
  if(i < 10000) intsTK.push(r);
  intsM.push(r);
}

function toJSON(array) {
  return JSON.stringify(array);
}

function fromJSON(string) {
  return JSON.parse(string);
}

function toJoined(array) {
  return array.join(",");
}

function fromJoined(string) {
  return string.split(",");
}

function fromJSONJoined(string) {
  return string.slice(1, -1).split(",");
}

// With 10K
console.time('toJSON_10k');
let jsonTK = toJSON(intsTK);
console.timeEnd('toJSON_10k');

console.time('toJoined_10k');
let joinedTK = toJoined(intsTK);
console.timeEnd('toJoined_10k');

console.time('fromJSON_10k');
fromJSON(jsonTK);
console.timeEnd('fromJSON_10k');

console.time('fromJoined_10k');
fromJoined(joinedTK);
console.timeEnd('fromJoined_10k');

console.time('fromJSONJoined_10k');
fromJSONJoined(jsonTK);
console.timeEnd('fromJSONJoined_10k');

//With 1 million
console.time('toJSON_1m');
let jsonM = toJSON(intsM);
console.timeEnd('toJSON_1m');

console.time('toJoined_1m');
let joinedM = toJoined(intsM);
console.timeEnd('toJoined_1m');

console.time('fromJSON_1m');
fromJSON(jsonM);
console.timeEnd('fromJSON_1m');

console.time('fromJoined_1m');
fromJoined(joinedM);
console.timeEnd('fromJoined_1m');

console.time('fromJSONJoined_1m');
fromJSONJoined(jsonM);
console.timeEnd('fromJSONJoined_1m');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look to this page:
https://jsben.ch/wQ9RU
It's a tool for Javascript performance, as you can see there, using `[].splice()` is better than `JSON.parse/JSON.stringify`

Comment: Ok, maybe, but that's not the question here. Storage API only can store strings.

Comment: If you want a shallow clone of an array (like in your link), then yes, `Array.splice` is normally "better" than `JSON.parse/JSON.stringify`.  These functions do very different things, so you shouldn't really make statements about which is generally "better".  It depends on the problem.